# Q&A. Trailbalzer Testing - Implications of contract method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trailblazer

The following Q&A is based on the examples given in the Trailblazer book pp. ~50-60 as adapted for my specific requirements.  You can simply think of `ARInvoice` and `ar_invoice` as `Thing` and `thing` to get the general drift if following in the book.

My `operation.rb` file for this was:

```
class ARInvoice < GLTransaction   class Create <
  Trailblazer::Operation

    include( Model )
    model( ARInvoice, :create )

    contract() do
      property( :invoice_number )
      property( :currency_code )
      property( :forex_rate )
      property( :gl_account_id )

      validates( :invoice_number, :presence => true )
      validates( :currency_code, :presence => true )
    end

    def process( params )
      @model = ARInvoice.new  # have to use instance variable here
      validate( params[ :ar_invoice ], @model ) do |f|
        f.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I adapted this test from the trailblazer book:

```
it("INSERTs a valid invoice") do
  test_time = Time.now
  puts(test_time)
  ar_invoice = ARInvoice::Create.(
    :ar_invoice => {
      :invoice_number => 101,
      :gl_account_id => 1,
      :effective_from => test_time.to_s
    }
  ).model

  ar_invoice.persisted?.must_equal(true)
  ar_invoice.invoice_number.must_equal(101)
  ar_invoice.transaction_type.must_equal('IN')
  ar_invoice.effective_from.must_equal(test_time)
  ar_invoice.superseded_after.must_equal(nil)
end
```

And I got this error:

```
ar_invoice crud Create#test_0001_INSERTs a valid invoice: \
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: \
gl_transactions.effective_from may not be NULL: \
INSERT INTO "gl_transactions" . . .
```

But I also see this:

```
# Running:
2016-02-08 11:24:35 -0500
E
```

So, test_time value is set.  Why is it not getting into the `effective_from` attribute?

The answer I give below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not grasp the significance of the `contract` `do/end` block as used in Trailblazer (TBR). The way I initially read the book was that the contract is concerned with the form. My experience with RoR led me to map the word *form* with the word *view*.  My mistake.  But one that might trip someone else as well.

The correct contract block contains the missing attribute: `effective_from`

```
contract() do
  property( :invoice_number )
  property( :currency_code )
  property( :forex_rate )
  property( :gl_account_id )

  property( :effective_from )

  validates( :invoice_number, :presence => true )
  validates( :currency_code, :presence => true )
end
```

For now, it helps me if I map the word `form` to `params[ :model ]`.  Because the attributes that are looked for in the `params[ :model ]` hash when the `process` method is called are limited to those attributes explicitly listed in the `contract` `do/end` block; *Which is why Strong Parameters are unneeded when using TBR*.

Note that the original test still fails because the `currency_code` validation is not met.  But that was intentional at the time this test was written.